# Suggestions on how to achieve circular "hole" in environment

Tags: unity, c#

I'm working on a 2D Sidescroller and I'm wanting to achieve a object that when activated it creates a port-hole to the sprites underneath, giving the appearance of the object "cleansing" the area.

[image: Edited image showing desired effect]

*Edited image showing the desired effect*

At this point I have no idea how to achieve this and am after suggestions, thanks!

Comment: You may find an answer in this [earlier question about "world healing" effects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69561/how-do-i-create-a-world-healing-wave-effect), or [this question about season change effects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137975/season-change-reveal-effect).

Comment: Here’s a great tutorial on making fake holes in Unity with shaders. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cHhxs12ZfSQ

Answer (score 1):

Several options here.

If your "cleansing area" thing is "just" a color swap, you can do that using a custom shader that will take original pixel colors and swap them with a given palette. Then it'll change purple pixels to light green, dark blue to light blue...

If color swapping is not what you're looking for and you have actually two versions of the same level (one dark, one clean), you have to have the both version in your actual game scene. Using two cameras, one for dark and one for light. The light camera will render into a render texture instead of the screen. With that render texture you'll be able to only display part of it. Using a custom shader you'll be able to show what's around the player or any part you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sprite mask for this, maybe several depending on exactly what you want to do. You would need multiple sprites, for example, a "dirty" trashcan and a "clean" trashcan both at the same position but they respond to the mask differently. The "dirty" sprite would be visible outside the mask, and the "clean" sprite visible inside the mask.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html

This sounds like a really cool idea, I hope it works out well for you.